# property of Undefined in nodejs 3 session

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have been stuck with this issue where i'm trying to use Session in Nodejs
but every time it returns cannot set Property "something" of undefined

I have installed express-session and cookie-parser
 the Error Im getting  is

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'userId' of undefined
at \testSession\app.js:88:23
at callbacks
```

the code can be found here :

```
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
secret: 'mYsEcReTkEy',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.post('/login', function(req,res){
  var id=12345;
  req.session.userId = id;
  res.send(200);
});

app.get('/', function(req,res){
 var html = '<form action="/login" method="post">' +
 'Your name: <input type="text" name="userId"><br>' +
 '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
 '</form>';
 res.send(html);
});

app.get('/hello', function(req,res){
  var id=req.session.userId;
  console.log("Hello",id);
  res.send(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `cookie-parser` may interfere with `express-session`, so try without that.